# Social sharing url of current webview iPhone. ( Xcode)

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, twitter

so I have my app setup with share action button that shares the current URL to Twitter or Facebook however when I click the Facebook button it shows a Twiiter share sheet. The (Tiwtter option works fine)

After I click the FACEBOOK option, when testing on iPhone the standard twiiter share sheet appears.

```
- (IBAction)social:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *share = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pass on the news!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Post to Twitter", @"Post to Facebook", nil];

    //You must show the action sheet for the user to see it.
    [share showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

//Each button title we gave to our action sheet is given a tag starting with 0.
if (actionSheet.tag == 0) {

    //Check Twitter accessibility and at least one account is setup.
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[tweetSheet addURL:self.newsItemWebView.request.URL];            //This is setting the initial text for our share card.
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Check out this article I found using the 'Pass'  iPhone app:,  "];

        //Brings up the little share card with the test we have pre defind.
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {
        //This alreat tells the user that they can't use built in socal interegration and why they can't.
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure you have at least one Twitter account setup and your device is using iOS6 or above!." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }


} else if (actionSheet.tag == 1) {

    //Check Facebook accessibility and at least one account is setup.
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *facebookSheet =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [facebookSheet addURL:self.newsItemWebView.request.URL];
        //This is setting the initial text for our share card.
        [facebookSheet setInitialText:@"Check out this article I found using the 'Pass'  iPhone app:"];

        //Brings up the little share card with the test we have pre defind.
        [self presentViewController:facebookSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {
        //This alreat tells the user that they can't use built in socal interegration and why they can't.
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't post a Facebook post right now, make sure you have at least one Facebook account setup and your device is using iOS6 or above!." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: Why not use the [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ?

Comment: @rckoenes Yeah, im very new to this but that sounds like a far better way of doing it! Would i still be able to use addURL:self.newsItemWebView.request.URL line to add the current URL to the share sheet? Thanks very much pal!

Comment: Well no, you will need to pass some object you want to share. Just add the URL to an array and pass it to the `[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];` where the `items` is an array containing you URL.

Comment: @rckoens Great thanks very much, i'll give it a try when i'm back at my computer and mark as answered then! (:  Out of interest do you know why It wasn't working with my method? Its bugging me still.

Comment: You are using `actionSheet.tag` and not `buttonIndex` in your if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `actionSheet.tag` which will be the same for the entiere actionsheet. 
If you want to know which button is pressed you should use `buttonIndex` in your if statements.

Even better is to use [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSArray *items = @[self.newsItemWebView.request.URL];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    // do any thing you want when the user finishes the share activity.
    // Like present a message that that activity has completed or not.
};

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```